# how to hide partner name and address from the top of odoo invoice report?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, odoo, qweb

I'm trying to customize odoo invoice report firts thing  had tried to do is to hide the partner details form the top left of the page 
this how it wrote in the original report

```
<template id="report_invoice_document">
        <t t-call="web.external_layout">
            <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(lang=lang)" />
            <t t-set="address">
                <address t-field="o.partner_id" t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": True}' />
                <div t-if="o.partner_id.vat" class="mt16"><t t-esc="o.company_id.country_id.vat_label or 'Tax ID'"/>
                    :
                    <span t-field="o.partner_id.vat"/>
                </div>
            </t>   
.
.
.
.
.
```

then I'm tried to hide and it work partially because the partner name still appear 
this what I had done

```
<odoo>
<data>
    <template id="test_inherit"  inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document" >
            <xpath expr="//t[@t-set='address']/address"  position="attributes">
            <attribute name="t-options"></attribute>
        </xpath>
</data>
</odoo>
```

this hide the address but not the partner name 
like the image below 
how can I do it ?
any help will be appreciated [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mohamed Fouad

You can try this,

```
<xpath expr="//t[@t-set='address']"  position="replace"></xpath>
```